# 2D - plane, 3D -?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe 3D space like *plane* describes 2D space?

Comment: Mathematicians use the word _manifold_ for a space of any particular dimension, but it is not in common use.

Comment: @ColinFine i think they use manifold for something which locally resembles space of some dimension. Say, sphere is a two-manifold.

Comment: In common terms it's a *space*.

Comment: 'Plane' is only one form of 2-D space in some geometries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one set of [definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry)):

> A *plane* is the two-dimensional analogue of a *point* (zero dimensions), a *line* (one dimension) and **three-dimensional space**.

[Also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-dimensional_space):

> **Three-dimensional space** (also: **3-space** or, rarely, **tri-dimensional space**) is a geometric setting in which three values (called parameters) are required to determine the position of an element (i.e., point).

Not surprisingly, [**3D space**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42640/calculate-distance-in-3d-space) is also a term that's used. But it's interesting that there is no single "word" for this as opposed to a generic noun with a qualifying adjective.

As a result, the actual answer to your question is, "No, '3D space' has no other word to describe it."

Comment: Hmm.. 3space might be an option for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you just want

> space

which can refer to [any number of dimensions](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/space#Noun) (most commonly 3 or more).

You could also try "volume" but that's more often used to mean a specific quantity of space, like the volume inside a bottle of water, rather than a 3D region and any points within that.

Comment: *Volume* is pretty good. Need to think about it.

Comment: @Yola *Volume* is close, but it's not quite there. I think that what you want to put into your question is: ***Area*** *is to* ***volume*** *as* ***plane*** *is to ___.*